# Spectrum table Manifest file when S3 file size is in decimal

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, manifest, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am reading a S3 file by creating a Spectrum external table and pointing it to a manifest file which contains the information about the source S3 file.
The problem is when my S3 file size is in decimal for e.g. 37.5 MB or 100.2 KB.

As per the documentation, we need to provide the file size in bytes. Now when I am using a multiplier of 1000 to convert to bytes, I am loosing some records or some data at the end of the file in the external table.
But when I use a multiplier of 1024 to convert to bytes, my converted file size would be in decimal.

Consider I have a file size 100.2 KB, so in bytes it would be 102604.8 Bytes.

1. When I provide the file size as 102604.8 in manifest file, I get an
   error "File entry does not have content length set"
2. When I provide a rounded value to the next integer, 102605, I get an error "Spectrum Error"
3. When I provide a rounded value to the previous integer, 102604, I again get same error "Spectrum Error"

My manifest looks like:

```
{

  "entries": [

    {"url":"s3://path/filename1.csv", "meta": { "content_length": 102605 } },

    {"url":"s3://path/filename2.csv", "meta": { "content_length": 102605 } }

  ]

}
```

Does anybody here faced such scenario and can share their inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what is the actual size of the file?

> Consider I have a file size 100.2 KB, so in bytes it would be 102604.8 Bytes.

The value of `100.2 KB` is not the exact file size in bytes. Your file will always have the full number of bytes of size (as data is stored in bytes in memory).

You can check the size of the file by copying it to your local computer and calling

```
stat -f%z my_file.csv
```

Also you can directly check the metadata of the s3 object with eg. aws cli

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket my_bucket --key my_objects_key --query 'ContentLength'
```

In our system we are using the latter (but using boto3 python library) to assemble the manifest file and it works without any problems.

For the debugging you could also have a look into some internal Redshift tables like [STL_ERROR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_ERROR.html) or [SVL_S3LOG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_S3LOG.html).

Comment: Thanks @botchniaque Since i was only looking at the size in S3 bucket, i faced this problem. I  tried both windows file properties and cli command to get the exact size and now it works fine.